# One view for multiple pages?

Tags: views, paging

I have nodes from a content type that are put in a paged view (show 1/page)
You can see it here: 
http://stage.e-clear.eu/en/chemicali%C3%ABn
http://stage.e-clear.eu/en/Energie
As you see this are multiple views for multiple pages (in example chemicals and energy)

I want a view that creates multiple pages like a published filter but invisible with nice url's like /energy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here.  Can you re-word your question to one sentence?

Comment: I did my best re-wording.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are using a paged view as a menu'ing system, and want to remove ?page=xxx  from the url?

Comment: no that's fine. It's actually perfect in my examples but I made for every page a new view with 1 little different filter so i think this can better (this is inefficient). An exposed filter would do it but I don't want to expose a filter and i want a nice url as it is now.

Comment: You could set up each view as a block. Write a custom template that includes rendering of those blocks in hidden div`s, and use some jQuery to create a fancy menu system, so the url doesn`t change, even when the content does. Therefore, regardless of which `view`is showing, the url won`t change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you're trying to do with Views, and it's easier than you think once you get comfortable with Views Contextual Filters.

Check out this video (or the text version article) that clearly walks through how to use Drupal Views Contextual Filters. The linked examples use Pets (Dogs, Cats) as sample data, so you'll see how to filter Cats versus Dogs quickly.

**VIDEO:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJFMTDuaxy8 (YouTube video short-url: lJFMTDuaxy8)

**ARTICLE:** http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what I was looking for. But now I would like automatic generated menu entries, I thought a menutab would work but it didn't So do you know anything?

Comment: never mind i created a view for it